# How do I cast a decimal field to a date field in DB2 AS/400?

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange

I have a DECIMAL field which contains a date in the AS400 format: 1100614

I have tried:

```
cast (MYDATE as DATE)
```

but I can't cast a DECIMAL to DATE, whereas

```
DATE(MYDATE)
```

returns null.

How do I cast this field in a DATE field?

Comment: Is that CYYMMDD? Where 1 = 20? So that would be 20100614?

Comment: The problem is that "CYYMMDD" isn't exactly "AS/400 format". It's a format used by many past (and present) developers because they didn't know how to handle true DATE values and because it originated before true database DATE definitions really even existed. Inertia has kept the form around a couple decades past its usefulness. A modern DATE value on the system doesn't look like that and hasn't for a long time. It's unfortunate that it's still in so many tables.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it is CYYMMDD like I asked in my comment above, here are a couple options:

1. [Convert CYYMMDD format to datetime - SQL](http://vijirajkumar.blogspot.com/2010/05/convert-cyymmdd-format-to-datetime-sql.html)
2. [convert cyymmdd (AS400) format to datetime format](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=35560)

It can be done, but it isn't easy. If you need to do this often, it may be worth your time writing your own function to do this.

Comment: I was hoping that I could CAST in a date format with the built-in functions.

Comment: @kevin I looked through IBM's manual and I didn't see any support for CYYMMDD.

Answer (score 0):

At a recent DB2 for IBM i class I attended, IBM folks were suggesting a pre-populated conversion table, that contains the date values in all the different formats you need to support.  You only need 365 or 366 rows per year. You then join to this table to convert. Of course you'll need to create the indexes for each format to have good performance. One guy stated the performing the join could even be faster than calling a conversion function.

Another advantage is that you can add other columns in the conversion table such as the fiscal period, the quarter, business day indicator, etc, which can simplify a bunch of queries, such as finding all orders in the third quarter.

For instance, say the DATECONV table has columns DATEFMT as a real date and CYMDFMT as the decimal date, your select would be
SELECT DATEFMT, ... 
FROM MYTABLE JOIN DATECONV on CYMDFMT=MYDATE

One issue with this solution is that if you use invalid dates as special values such as 9999999 as you can't have invalid dates in the real date field.  But then you can't convert them anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This will work if you're on IBM i release 6.1 or newer, but I have a hunch you're on an old version of the operating system.  I stole the adding trick from [this forum post](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5208-3513-0.html?forumID=101&threadID=278438&messageID=3091374&tag=content;leftCol).

```
create table dec1 (f1 decimal(7,0))
insert into dec1 values 1100614

select date(timestamp_format(char(f1+19000000), 'YYYYMMDD')) from dec1
```

Results:

```
DATE                           
06/14/10                       
********  End of data  ********
```

[Here's the reference](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/db2/rbafzdatestrings.htm) to the supported date string formats in DB2 for i SQL.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler (and more suitable if you want your own function) way to do this would be

```
SELECT CAST(CAST(*DecimalDateFromDB2_Here* + 19000000 AS VARCHAR) AS DATETIME)
```

## Example:

-Showing 2000 + dates

```
SELECT CAST(CAST(1040526 + 19000000 AS VARCHAR) AS DATETIME)
```

-Showing 1999 + dates

```
SELECT CAST(CAST(990526 + 19000000 AS VARCHAR) AS DATETIME)
```

Answer (score 0):

An [and rather *simple*] expression verified to function as far back as v5r3, and for which the MYDATE column may be defined as any of CHAR(7), DEC(7), NUMERIC(7), INTEGER or FLOAT data types [or a larger length/precision variant of those types] follows; the DATE casting scalar shown in this example, is converting the result of a character-string expression [per CONCAT] that yields a 14-character string that will be valid as a TIMESTAMP with the format `'YYYYMMDDHHMMSS'`:

```
DATE( DEC( 19000000 + MYDATE, 8, 0 ) CONCAT '000000' )
```

Note: The above expression may be [seen elsewhere] written with a DIGITS casting scalar for the DECIMAL casting result, but that would be superfluous given the addition of a value with a full 8-digits of precision, and *implicit cast* from numeric to character for the DEC() expression; the DIGITS is required when dealing with dates prior to year 1000 to ensure a leading zero in the string result, or on some even older releases where there is no capability of *implicit cast* from numeric to character.

[IBM i 7.2->Database->Reference->SQL reference->Language elements->Data types->Datetime values->String representations of datetime values->Timestamp strings](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_72/db2/rbafztsstrings.htm)